# bootstrap – responsive nav does not pull down

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

This is confusing! I am working on my first website with bootstrap, and it is even finished. But the mobile navigation menu and the collapsed menu are not pulling down on click.

I've used this starter template: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/

This is the website: http://www.beamcase.de

Here's my code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="http://www.beamcase.de">BeamCase</a></li>
        <li><a href="fly.php">BeamCase FLY</a></li>
            <li><a href="kontakt.php">Kontakt</a></li>
        <li><a href="impressum.php">Impressum</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please provide jsfiddle link.

Comment: Hey Mahadevan, which code do you want me to share via jsfiddle?

Comment: When i take a look to your website, I can't see any JS to display your menu... Did you had this JS ?

Comment: you should use `jquery` to get the desired output.

Comment: @injuvik hi code which you provided. In my work area i can not able to see your webiste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should load this `Jquery` file to get that collapsed menu to pull down on click.

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js

OR

include in your body tag like

```
<script type="text/javascripts" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" />
```

Comment: ah! Okay! Where shall i place it? in the footer? Or in the header?

Comment: Okay, JQuery is in the footer now, but the menu is still not pulling down. What's wrong?

http://beamcase.de/

Comment: It needs to be in the `<head>` section with the CSS and any other JavaScript sources.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason for my problem: I simply did not include the bootstrap.min.js. Now everything is fine! Thank you all!